# Type aliasing of Lists results in same type after erasure

Tags: scala

When using type aliasing to define lists of two different traits as their own type, I am hit with the error message: `error: double definition: func and def func have same type after erasure`.

I have read about type erasures, but can't seem to come up with a solution.
So, how can I circumvent this issue?

---

This is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
sealed trait A
sealed trait B

type AList = List[A]
type BList = List[B]

def func(l: AList): AList = l
def func(l: BList): BList = l
```

Comment: Note though that defining a type alias like this does not create a "new" type. It is _literally_ an alias. I.e. in `type A = Int; type B = Int` values of types `A`, `B`, and `Int` are completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disambiguating with `DummyImplicit` like so

```
def func(l: AList): AList = l
def func(l: BList)(implicit ev: DummyImplicit): BList = l

val aList = List(new A {})
val bList = List(new B {})

func(aList)  // ok
func(bList)  // ok
```

This works because compiler `-Xprint:jvm` translates it to something like

```
def func(l: List): List = l;
def func(l: List, ev: DummyImplicit): List = l;

func(aList);
func(bList, scala.DummyImplicit.dummyImplicit);
```